# Python has or not access modifiers?

Tags: python

I found from the internet:

```
public="a"  # is a public variable
_protected="b"  # is a protected variable
__private="c"  # is a private variable
```

Example of code:

```
class c1:
    def __init__(self,a,b,c):
        self.public=a
        self._protected=b
        self.__private=c
v=c1("A","B","C")
print(v.public)
v._protected="Be"   # !??? I can access a protected variable
print(v._protected)
print(v.__private)  # !??? AttributeError: 'c1' object has no attribute  '__private'
```

I can access a protected variable!?

Comment: Yes you can. Note that you can also dynamically add / replace / remove instance and class attributes (including methods, which are technically class attributes), and even change the class of an instance at runtime.

Comment: **Python does not have access modifiers**. People try to draw analogies, but they are misleading.

Answer (score 3):

No, Python does not have access modifiers which outright prevent access. But then again, *most languages don't.* Even languages which sport `protected` and `private` keywords usually have some way through introspection or such to get at the value anyway in ways which "should not be allowed."

Access modifiers are, one way or another, just a hint as to how the property is supposed to be used.

Python's philosophy is to assume that everyone contributing code is a responsible adult, and that a ***hint*** in the form of one or two underscores is perfectly enough to prevent "unauthorised access" to a property. If it starts with an underscore, you probably shouldn't mess with it.

Comment: "But then again, most languages don't."  What languges? What programing languages you know?
php,JAVA,C# - have access modifiers.
even JavaScript has in a way access modifiers.

Comment: As a PHP example: `(new ReflectionObject($foo))->getProperty('bar')->setAccessible(true)`... Oops, there goes your "protected property". Not to mention `(array)$foo` and then picking through the keys. – Access modifiers **are not "security".** They're always just hints to the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

You could acess your protected variable as:

```
print(v._c1__private)
'C'
```

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have modifiers like `private`, `protected`, `public`. You can emulate their behavior with `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__`, but it's not a Pythonic way to write programs.

Using single underscore `_` is a convention, so when you see an attribute or method starting with one underscore, consider that library developer didn't expect it to be part of public API. Also when executing `from module import *` Python interpreter doesn't import names starting with `_`, though there're ways to modify this behavior.

Using double underscore `__` is not just a convention, it leads to "name-mangling" by interpreter - adding class name in front of attribute, so i.e.:

```
class Klass():
    def __like_private():
        print("Hey!")
```

will make `_Klass__like_private`.
You won't be able to access `__like_private` directly as defined, though you still will be able to get to it knowing how names are composed by using `_Klass__like_private()` in subclasses for example or in module:

`Klass.__like_private()` will give you an error.

`Klass._Klass__like_private()` will print `Hey!`.